# No interactive markers displayed whilst following moveit! tutorial ROS Kinetic

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to using rviz and moveit and currently working through the following tutorials on ROS Kinetic:

1. http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html
2. http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html

I completed the first link, moving onto the second link (quickstart in rviz) and completing steps 1 and 2 I find that the interactive markers are not displaying. I am unsure where the errors lie here considering I have followed the instructions perfectly.

When examining the terminal which launches moveit tutorial I see that I have a warning. I'm not sure how relevant it will be but I have included it anyway:

```
[ WARN] [1550244405.694068338]: Unable to update multi-DOF joint 'virtual_joint': TF has no common time between '/world' and 'panda_link0':
```

Further searching around I have found that this issue may have popped up before: https://answers.ros.org/question/278820/moveit-interactive-marker-missing-on-new-kinetic-version/

However the link to the discussion is something beyond me and it doesn't seem to appear to be instructions to fix it. Unsure where to go from here and would appreciate any suggestions to fixes. Please let me know if more information is required from logs etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315758/no-interactive-markers-displayed-whilst-following-moveit!-tutorial-ros-kinetic/) by [Burarara](https://answers.ros.org/users/40052/burarara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2019-02-15

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benb35](https://answers.ros.org/users/40131/benb35/) on 2019-02-20**:
Having the same issue

**Comment by [kevin29](https://answers.ros.org/users/40157/kevin29/) on 2019-02-22**:
I have the same problem, please let me know if someone finds a solution!

I get an also an info, that *"Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED*" because "*OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3)*". This might be because I have got a machine with an Intel on board graphics...

Do you also get this? Might this be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although I did not seem to find a permanent solution to the downloaded demo not displaying interactive markers, I did however find an alternative way to work around it. Simply following the instructions of the next step in the tutorials, the setup assistant tutorial (http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html), will ask you to delete the panda demo folder and you will replace it yourself with a new panda which you create yourself. After this I found that interactive markers were now displaying on the new panda so I could go back and explore the previous tutorial.

I don't have an ideal fix to this, nor do I have a concrete answer as to why the demo panda does not display it (I suspect it to be linked with the end effector of the panda not being properly configured) but hopefully this will allow anyone working with moveit for the first time to continue with the tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [Burarara](https://answers.ros.org/users/40052/burarara/) with karma: 66 on 2019-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Conan](https://answers.ros.org/users/40300/conan/) on 2019-03-03**:
Having the same problem,but thank you for the answer since the assistant can repair it.

**Comment by [rebecatourinho](https://answers.ros.org/users/36538/rebecatourinho/) on 2019-04-04**:
This way worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the problem is solved on my machine. I have now uninstalled all moveIt packages that I had installed in the past according to: https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html.

Because I had also installed "libfranka" and "franka_ros" (https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/installation.html), I have also uninstalled it to have a clean system.

After this, I tried to reinstall everything, but this time not by building "libfranka" and "franka_ros" from source, but rather by installing it from ROS repositories (https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/installation.html#installing-from-the-ros-repositories). After the installation of this two packages, the problem was solved, and I didnt need to install further moveIt packages from https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html.

Hope this helps someone else also..

---

Originally posted by [kevin29](https://answers.ros.org/users/40157/kevin29/) with karma: 11 on 2019-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Burarara](https://answers.ros.org/users/40052/burarara/) on 2019-02-22**:
Thank you for this, although I did find a way to work around it I will keep this in mind should an issue with the interactive marker reappear in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This happened because the recent update of panda_moveit_config package. Try to reverse to 03bb4 commit and recompile the package then restart the launch file, the markers will appear.

---

Originally posted by [yakunix](https://answers.ros.org/users/40229/yakunix/) with karma: 21 on 2019-02-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [an_nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/40377/an_nguyen/) on 2019-03-07**:
Thanks. This works for me! (on ROS Melodic)

**Comment by [tien dang](https://answers.ros.org/users/40456/tien-dang/) on 2019-03-13**:
how can i do that, i dont understand .

**Comment by [hoang_chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41133/hoang_chu/) on 2019-04-30**:
cd to panda_moveit_config and git checkout 03bb4 :)))

**Comment by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on 2019-05-02**:
Encountered the same "No Interactive markers" problem on ROS Kinetic Branch: kinetic-devel Feb 9, 2019 commit 142fb79. Solved the same way by reverse to 3a1e58d Nov. 9, 2018 with git checkout, recompile & restart launch, the markers appear following the Moveit! Tutorial procedure.

**Comment by [sosalau](https://answers.ros.org/users/38493/sosalau/) on 2020-01-24**:
Please, I don't understand. Can you be explicit? I couldn't find the commit on Github. Please help me understand how to fix the interactive marker problem on ROS Kinetic. Thank you @Red24Dog, @an_nguyen, @hoang_chu and @yakunix

**Comment by [an_nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/40377/an_nguyen/) on 2020-01-24**:
@sosalau the commit id starts with "03bb4". Just git clone the repo https://github.com/ros-planning/panda_moveit_config and `git checkout 03bb4` then you will get to it.

**Comment by [sosalau](https://answers.ros.org/users/38493/sosalau/) on 2020-01-25**:
Thank you @an_nguyen. It works, I can now see the interactive markers.